# Custom UICollectionViewCell class: how to change height in Swift 3

Tags: swift, layout, uicollectionview

How can I change the size of my UICollectionViewCell within my class file?

Here's my code (or rather a snippet of my code with the relevant function):

```
class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell {

func resizeToText(text: String) {

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, animations: {

        let oldSize = self.feedTextView.frame.size
        var newSize = estimatedFrameForText(text: text, contentViewWidth: oldSize.width, maxSize: 500, font: self.feedTextView.font!, fontSize: self.feedTextView.font!.pointSize)

        newSize.width = oldSize.width

        self.feedTextView.frame.size = newSize

        let heightDiff = oldSize.height - newSize.height



        self.feedImageView.frame.origin.y -= heightDiff

        self.mainView.frame.size.height -= heightDiff

        // I'm changing the cells size but it doesn't change :(
        self.contentView.frame.size.height -= heightDiff


        let oldSize2 = self.feedTextView.frame.size
        let newSize2 = self.feedTextView.contentSize

        self.feedTextView.frame.size = self.feedTextView.contentSize

        let diff = oldSize2.height - newSize2.height

        self.feedImageView.frame.origin.y -= diff

        self.mainView.frame.size.height -= diff

        // here again!
        self.contentView.frame.size.height -= diff

        self.mainView.dropShadowFeed(scale: true)

    })

}
```

}

I've also tried self.frame.size.height but it doesn't work either.

**My goal is that the cell is in a feed and manually resizes to the text that it's showing**. How do I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame of UICollectionViewCell is determined by the delegate below:

```
(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

If you want to set frame of your collectionviewcell, you need to set it at this delegate function. Another option is using "Dynamic Cell Size".